in AGOL how can I get the form from one webmap onto a copy of the featurelayer in another webmap?
I have a form in Fieldmaps Designer that was used last year on a project whose FeatureLayer has since been deleted.  That FeatureLayer now shows up on FieldMaps Designer greyed out with exclamation marks.  Prior to deletion, the FeatureLayer was copied and made into a new version for this year, so same layers and attributes, just a different title and living in a new webmap.
I would like to avoid rebuilding all the drop-downs and the layout of the forms for each of the layers in the deleted FeatureLayer, so I am hoping there is a way to either re-point the broken links version of the form to the FeatureLayer copy for this year, or if I can't re-point it, can a copy of the form be made and assigned to the new FeatureLayer even if the old form is broken?
I have investigated the AGOL Assistant and editing of JSON file, but so far no luck in finding the things in the JSON that the ESRI help page on it is referring to, so hoping someone here has other ideas.  I am not programmer-savvy.
There may be a few ways to handle this, but ultimately the goal is to take the form from one FeatureLayer and apply it to another FeatureLayer.
